# wampapache won't start after installing openemr

Tags: wamp, port80

I was using WampServer's fine. But after installing openEMR I noticed it is not starting anymore. When I test port 80 it shows the following error

***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====

Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 seems not actually used.
Unable to initiate a socket connection
Error number: 10060 - Error string: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMKis.png)

I have tried everything online relating to this topic but nothing works.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).